# I really want to know why it lacks on performance issues, can you tell me?

Tags: c#, performance, loops, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I got a challenge today to calculate a Euclidean Distance on the CodeSignal website.

The last solution I've tried got success on all the tests but failed in performance.

```
public static double solution(int[][] p)
    {
        double bestDistance = double.MaxValue;
        int plength = p.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < plength - 1; i++)
        {
            double x = p[i][0];
            double y = p[i][1];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < plength; j++)
            {
                double a = p[j][0];
                double b = p[j][1];

                var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x - a, 2) + Math.Pow(y - b, 2));
                if (distance < bestDistance)
                    bestDistance = distance;
            }
        }

        return bestDistance;
    }
```

The first array gets every point on a cartesian map. The second is always 0 and 1 positions, for axis x and y. So, I have to iterate over all the existing points and check which distance is smaller between any 2 points.
All the tests passed but failed for performance and I really don't know why.

Comment: You are defeating cache by indexing that way

Comment: Also you should run a profiler. That will tell you the hotspots

Comment: Don't use a jagged array when you only need a single dimensional array of structs.  Don't use Pow(x, 2) when x * x will do.  Don't use Math.Sqrt() when you don't need it for comparison.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielA.White, I'll read about the profiler. If you have any tips to give me the way, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @HansPassant for the challenge purpose, the int[][] already comes with the question, so, I can't change it. But your other tips really work. nice to know, thanks

Comment: I hope you are running the program in release mode with optimizations enabled.

Comment: If you hope for some help, you should first of all state what challenge is about. Add problem description *HERE*. Because that description might contain some hint which helps to avoid using nested loops

Comment: Checking every pair is inherently inefficient. There are more efficient ways to solve the [closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem).

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert, so, the tests look much more about algorithm knowledge than my capacity to find a solution. Even with the solution using a known algorithm, the challenges become with the advice of not researching for solutions, and I never heard about this algorithm before. Thanks anyway. You can make it an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am going to trust that we're not cheating together in a test :)

So in this case it's about keeping the CPU off duty as much as possible, so we don't want to compute anything twice, unless it's fair to assume that the lookup is more expensive than the calculation.

Then below, besides setting up test data and instrumentation you'll get consistently over 55% if you cache the result of the Math.Pow operations, think Do play around with it more I am sure You can reduce more (?)

```
[Fact]
public void EuclidifyTest() {
    Exception exception = null;
    try{
        int sampleCount = 8000;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Sample count: {sampleCount}, generating unique data");
        var rnd = new Random();

        var samplesArray = new int[sampleCount, 2];

        bool alreadyInSet(int x, int y){
            for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
            {
                if(samplesArray[i, 0] == x && samplesArray[i,1] == y)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        {
            var nextX = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            var nextY = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            while(alreadyInSet(nextX, nextY)){
                nextX = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
                nextY = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            }
            samplesArray[i, 0] =  nextX;
            samplesArray[i, 1] =  nextY;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine($"Samples ready");
        var samplesArrayJaggar = new int[sampleCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++){
            samplesArrayJaggar[i] = new int[]{ samplesArray[i,0], samplesArray[i,1] };
        }

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var dblFirst = solution(samplesArrayJaggar);
        sw.Stop();
        var timeFirst = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"First way result in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms, produced shortest distance {dblFirst:0.0000000} ");

        sw.Restart();
        var dblSecond = speedUp(samplesArray);
        sw.Stop();
        var timeSecond = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Second way result in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms, produced shortest distance {dblSecond:0.0000000} ");

        var diff = timeFirst- timeSecond;

        var pctImprove = (double)diff/timeFirst * 100;

        Debug.WriteLine($"Improvement {pctImprove:0.0}%");

    }catch(Exception ex){
        exception = ex;
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    Assert.Null(exception);
}

static double speedUp(int[,] samplesArray) {
    int samplesLength = samplesArray.GetLength(0);
    var powersDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>(samplesLength);

    double getOr(int dist){
        if(powersDictionary.TryGetValue(dist, out double found)){
           return found;
        }
        var exp = Math.Pow(dist, 2);
        powersDictionary.Add(dist, exp);
        return exp;
    }

    int distX;
    int distY;
    double lowestExponent = 0;
    double expSum;

    for (int i = 0; i < samplesLength; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1;j < samplesLength; j++){
            distX = samplesArray[i, 0] - samplesArray[j, 0];
            distY = samplesArray[i, 1] - samplesArray[j, 1];
            expSum = getOr(distX) + getOr(distY);
            if(i == 0)
                lowestExponent = expSum;
            else
                lowestExponent = lowestExponent > expSum ? expSum : lowestExponent;
        }
    }

    return Math.Sqrt(lowestExponent);
}

//Your solution copy pasted in
public static double solution(int[][] p)
{
    double bestDistance = double.MaxValue;
    int plength = p.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < plength - 1; i++)
    {
        double x = p[i][0];
        double y = p[i][1];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < plength; j++)
        {
            double a = p[j][0];
            double b = p[j][1];

            var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x - a, 2) + Math.Pow(y - b, 2));
            if (distance < bestDistance)
                bestDistance = distance;
        }
    }

    return bestDistance;
}
```

Update:
well anyway got curious to squeeze a bit more, so next up to not violate the relative simplicy too much could be to go parallel.
Here i'm seeing a relative improvement of consistently above 82% obviously these gains will increase with the size of the set

```
static double speedUpMore(int[,] samplesArray) {
    int samplesLength = samplesArray.GetLength(0);
    var powersDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>(samplesLength);
    
    double getOr(int dist){
        if(powersDictionary.TryGetValue(dist, out double found)){
           return found;
        }
        var exp = Math.Pow(dist, 2);
        powersDictionary.TryAdd(dist, exp);
        return exp;
    }

    double handleBatch(object batchBorders){
        
        var fromTo = (int[])batchBorders;
        var sampleCount = fromTo[2];
        double? lowestLocal = null;                
        for(int i = fromTo[0];i <= fromTo[1]; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j< sampleCount; j++){
                var distX = samplesArray[i, 0] - samplesArray[j, 0];
                var distY = samplesArray[i, 1] - samplesArray[j, 1];
                var expSum = getOr(distX) + getOr(distY);                        
                if(j == fromTo[0] + 1)
                    lowestLocal = expSum;
                else
                    lowestLocal = lowestLocal > expSum ? expSum : lowestLocal;
            }
        }                
        return lowestLocal.Value;
    }

    double batchNumbers = 10.0;
    var batchSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(  samplesLength / batchNumbers);
                            
    var tasksList = new List<Task<double>>(10);
    int idxFrom;
    int idxTo;
    for(int i = 0; i < batchNumbers; i++){
        idxFrom = i + (i * batchSize);
        if(i < (batchNumbers-1.0))
            idxTo = i + (i * batchSize) + batchSize;
        else
            idxTo = samplesLength -1;
        
        tasksList.Add(Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(
                (batchBorders) =>  handleBatch(batchBorders), 
                new int[]{idxFrom, idxTo, samplesLength})
            );
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasksList.ToArray());
    double lowestExponent = 0;
    foreach(var doneTask in tasksList){
        if(!doneTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new Exception("Unexpected consequences");
        if (lowestExponent == 0){
            lowestExponent = doneTask.Result;
        } else if(doneTask.Result < lowestExponent){
            lowestExponent = doneTask.Result;
        }
    }
    return lowestExponent;
}
```

Comment: Btw the test framework to run it in is xUnit

Comment: No, rofl, there is no way to cheat because the test just finished. Is a 40 minutes test. I was curious about why I was falling and saved my own code to ask and learn about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just improved a little my source and got an even better time. The @DanielA.White comment is enough to get a solution faster, and your answer made it possible to check it. Thanks